# After killing application foreground service stop on Android 7 but works on Android 6 and 8 device

Tags: android, service

I am using foreground service in my app, On Android M and Oreo it works perfectly but on Android 7 devices this service get stopped if we remove application from memory (Clear recent activities). Following is my Activity

```
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startService(start);
        }
    });

public void startService(View view) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ExampleService.class);
    serviceIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("appList",appList);
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this,serviceIntent);
}
```

In Service I am using:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flag,int startid) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);
    scannedApp = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("appList");

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getAPKFilePath();
        }
    });
    t.start();

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Example Service")
            .setContentText("Working in Background")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1,notification);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

In `getAPKFilePath();` method I am doing some heavy task. In Android 7 if app is present in memory then it works fine (If just press back button), But if removed from memory then its not working. Neither showing Notification icon.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is the Android 7 device a Samsung one?

Comment: No Its Lenovo, Also tried on emulator (Android 7) in that also it is nor working